# Pyspark get Schema from JSON file

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get `Pyspark` schema from a JSON file but when I am creating the schema using the variable in the Python code, I am able to see the variable type of `<class 'pyspark.sql.types.StructType'>` but when I am trying to get through JSON file it's showing type of `unicode`.

Is there any way to get `pyspark` schema through JSON file?

**JSON file Content:**

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                
"tediasessionclose_schema" : "StructType([ StructField('@timestamp', StringType()), StructField('message' , StructType([ StructField('componentAddress', StringType()), StructField('values', StructType([ StructField('confNum', StringType()), StructField('day', IntegerType())])"                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

**Pyspark Code:**

```
df = sc.read.json(hdfs_path, schema = jsonfile['tediasessionclose_schema'])
```

Comment: tediasessionclose_schema = StructType([                                                                                                                                                          
StructField('@timestamp', StringType()),                                                                                                                                               
StructField('message' , StructType([StructField('componentAddress', StringType()) StructField('values', StructType([StructField('confNum', StringType())]))])),StructField('day', IntegerType())])

Comment: Yes @RameshMaharjan I have multiple line in json file ..but for testing i let it only one.

Comment: yes @RameshMaharjan

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the schema by evaluating the string that you get from reading the json:

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, IntegerType, StructType

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([], schema = eval(data['tediasessionclose_schema']))
print(df.schema)
```

outputs:

```
StructType(List(StructField(@timestamp,StringType,true),StructField(message,StructType(List(StructField(componentAddress,StringType,true),StructField(values,StructType(List(StructField(confNum,StringType,true),StructField(day,IntegerType,true))),true))),true)))
```

where `test.json` is:

```
{"tediasessionclose_schema" : "StructType([ StructField('@timestamp', StringType()), StructField('message' , StructType([ StructField('componentAddress', StringType()), StructField('values', StructType([ StructField('confNum', StringType()), StructField('day', IntegerType())]))]))])"}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Florian, The general idea is i already have schema defined in json config file and pass schema from json config file at the time of reading data and trying to do same things..not working for me.

Comment: @SumitGupta Not sure what you are trying to say? In the answer above a json file with a schema in it is read, and the schema is passed to create a Dataframe. That should also work for reading data from hdfs. Why is it not working, what error do you encounter? Is it not just your json schema that is malformed?

Comment: Thanks @Florian, let me debug it.

Comment: @SumitGupta Please note that I added some brackets to your json file content to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @Florian , I am not able to understand why we need it extra )]))])

Comment: @SumitGupta I just added the brackets because they seemed to be missing; there were unmatched opening brackets.

Comment: @SumitGupta Hi, were you able to resolve your issue with this answer? If so, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to mark your question as resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

config_json file:

```
{"json_data_schema": ["contactId", "firstName", "lastName"]}
```

PySpark Application :

```
schema = StructType().add("contactId", StringType()).add("firstName", StringType()).add("lastName", StringType())
```

Reference: https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php

```
schema = StructType()
schema = map(lambda x: schema.add(x, StringType(), True), (data["json_data_schema"]))[0][0:]
```

Hope this solution works for you!

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any manual effort here. Spark comes with a built in feature to read JSON string, infer its schema and give it to a Struct format.

Just read the JSON data to a single column dataframe - df and here is the statement that can be used next:

`json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0])).schema`

Answer (score 0):

Shubham's answer is good (and fast) in scenarios where the schema is known to be consistent from one record to the next.  In some environments this may not be the case, and it becomes necessary to do a full scan of the field in question:

```
def get_json_field_struct(tablename, fieldname):
  df = spark.sql(f"""
                    select distinct 
                      t.{fieldname} 
                    from 
                      {tablename} t
                    """
                )
  field_schemax = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda x: x[fieldname]), samplingRatio=1.0).schema.jsonValue()
  #field_schema = StructType.fromJson(field_schemax)
  return field_schemax

schema_def = get_json_field_struct("some_db.some_table_name", "some_fieldname")
```